# ROR number_field_tag give error 'not a number'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

[image]

**Error Message**

[image]

I'm trying to insert a number value through 'number_field_tag' but keep getting the same error message. Does anyone know what is causing this?

**new.html.erb**

```
<% provide(:title, 'Products') %>

<h1>Products</h1>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages_p' %>

    <%= form_for([:admin, @product], :html => {multipart:true}) do |f| %>

      <%= f.label :title %>
      <%= f.text_field :title, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :description %>
      <%= f.text_area :description, :rows => 6, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.file_field :image %>

      <%= number_field_tag :stock_quantity, 1, min: 1, class: "form-control" %>

      <%= f.label :price %>
      <%= f.text_field :price, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.submit "Create product", class: "btn btn-primary" %>

    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

**products_controller.rb**

```
class Admin::ProductsController < Admin::BaseController
before_action :set_product, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :invalid_product

def index
@products = Product.all
end

def show
@product = Product.find(params[:id])
end

def new
@product = Product.new
end

def edit
end

def create
@product = Product.new(product_params)
  if @product.save
    redirect_to [:admin, @product], notice: 'Product was successfully created.' 
  else
    render :new 
end
end

def update

  if @product.update(product_params)
    redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully updated.' 
  else
    render :edit 
end
end

def destroy
@product.destroy
  redirect_to products_url, notice: 'Product was successfully destroyed.' 
end


private

def set_product
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
end

def product_params
  params.require(:product).permit(:title, :description, :image, :price, :stock_quantity)
end

def invalid_product
  logger.error "Attempt to access invalid cart #{params[:id]}"
  redirect_to products_url, notice: 'Invalid product'
end


end
```

**product model**

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessor :image
validates :title, :description, :image, presence: true
validates :price, numericality: {greater_than_or_equal_to: 0.01}
validates :title, uniqueness: true
validates :stock_quantity, numericality: { only_integer: true}
validates :image, allow_blank: true, format: {with: %r{\.(gif|jpg|png)\Z}i, message: 'must be a URL for GIF, JPG or PNG image.'}
mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
```

Answer (score 0):

solved the issue by replacing the quantity submit code with this:

```
      <%= f.label :stock_quantity %>
      <%= f.number_field :stock_quantity, min: 1, class: 'form-control' %>
```

can anyone enlighten me why 'number_field_tag' not working?

Comment: If you looked at the generated HTML code you would have seen that the name of the field: `name='stock_quantity'`, but controller's #product_params params.require(:product).permit(:title, :description, :image, :price, :stock_quantity) expects `name='product[stock_quantity]'`

Comment: thanks for the clarification. does it means 'f.number_field' is equally good to use?

Answer (score 0):

this solve it,

```
<%= number_field_tag 'product[stockquantity]', min: 1, class:"form-control" %>
```

thanks to previous commenters highlighting the html wordings.